# Eclipse to connect TFS

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I am using eclipse to connect to TFS. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. But I am getting the following error message - 
"Error occurred in wizard completion. More details are available in Eclipse platform log". What am I doing wrong? - Attached screen shot.[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTgy1.png)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've checked the log file and did not find anything unusual. Unfortunately I am unable to take a screenshot of the logfile as there are 1835 lines in the log file. I deleted eclipse form my PC. Then downloaded latest version of eclipse. Then I installed microsoft TFS plugin for eclipse. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you use the latest team explorer everywhere? How about other team members? Can they connect TFS on their machine?

Comment: There was no issue for other team members. I could not fix this issue but what I did finally was bit silly. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (my previous version as 14.04), and now eclipse is working fine. Many thanks for your help.